C# Generics - Constrain generic method parameter to have specific static method
I am working with auto-generated code classes, where every class Foo has an equivalent FooSerializer class with a static Serialize(Foo data) method.
I wanted to write a helper function that can execute the Serialize method (+ a bunch of other stuff) for any such class, by recieving two type params.
public void Serialize<Foo, FooSerializer>(Foo data)
{
  FooSerializer.Serialize(data);
}

But this cannot work, since it doesn't know that FooSerializer has the Serialize method, and FooSerializer does not derive from any generic interface that defines that method as based on Foo.
Is there a way to specify in the generic constraints that FooSerializer must have a Serialize method that recieves a param of type Foo?
In c++ I implemented this by simply making Foo and FooSerializer as template arguments. Wonder if there is a similar solution in c#.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members

Were the auto-generated code classes declared to be public partial?  Code generators often do this to allow the auto-generated classes to be extended in separate, manually created files without the need to modify the auto-generated code files themselves.

Sadly they are also not partial. Its a rather old internal service

@DanielA.White that's exacly what I was looking for! Thank you! We sadly are still stuck in .Net Framework 4.8 so we cant use this but its good to know it exists.

On modern runtimes (not .NET Framework etc), yes:
interface IFooSerializer<T>
{
    // pick your own API here; string, byte[], Stream, etc
    static abstract T Read(string value);
    static abstract string Write(T value);
}

class Consumer
{
    public void Serialize<Foo, FooSerializer>(Foo data)
        where FooSerializer : IFooSerializer<Foo>
    {
        var s = FooSerializer.Write(data);
        var clone = FooSerializer.Read(s);
    }
}

However, it may be easier to just use an instance serializer.
In the case of generated code, you might need to put the interface part in a partial class, i.e.
partial class MyType : IMyStaticInterfaceThing {}

which simply adds IMyStaticInterfaceThing to the MyType definition, but will happily resolve the static methods from the generated code.

Runnable version:
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

var obj = new Consumer().Serialize<MyType, MyJsonSerializer<MyType>>(
    new() { Name = "Fred" });
Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);

class MyType
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

interface IFooSerializer<T>
{
    static abstract T Read(string value);
    static abstract string Write(T value);
}

class MyJsonSerializer<T> : IFooSerializer<T>
{
    public static T Read(string value)
        => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value)!;

    public static string Write(T value)
        => JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>(value);
}
class Consumer
{
    public Foo Serialize<Foo, FooSerializer>(Foo data)
        where FooSerializer : IFooSerializer<Foo>
    {
        var s = FooSerializer.Write(data);
        return FooSerializer.Read(s); // clone
    }
}


Or an alternative construction using the partial class aspect:
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

var obj = new Consumer().DeepClone<MyType>(
    new() { Name = "Fred" });
Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);

partial class MyType // the generated half
{
    public static MyType Read(string value)
        => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType>(value)!;

    public static string Write(MyType value)
        => JsonSerializer.Serialize<MyType>(value);

    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

partial class MyType : ISerializable<MyType> { } // your half

interface ISerializable<T>
{
    // describe the API offered by the generated code
    static abstract T Read(string value);
    static abstract string Write(T value);
}

class Consumer
{
    public T DeepClone<T>(T data)
        where T: ISerializable<T>
    {
        var s = T.Write(data);
        return T.Read(s); // clone
    }
}


My problem is, the autogenerated code does not generate FooSerializer as a IFooSerializer where T is Foo, it just... is. And I sadly have no way to change that, I was wondering if I could constrain FooSerializer the param to have any specific method definition I wish without it deriving from any class

@TomerTrashman see the edit with the alternative construction (the code at the bottom)

Interesting, currently said code generator does not generate the classes as partial, but I like that solution so I might push to have that changed (and if I'm already going to touch that legacy service I'll also add the generic interface). Thank you!

@Daniel A. White also linked the feature documentation for exactly what I was asking for in C# 11. Our project is currently still in. Net Framework 4.8 so we cant use that, but its still good to know.
